# How to set the package/applicationId for android instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

My project structure contains a base feature module, an installed app module (with free and paid flavors) and an instant app module(only one flavor - free). It seems like the package name for the instant app is coming from the base feature module's manifest.

Why does not the applicationId field in build.gradle of instant app overwrite the package field in the manifest as it does for the installed app?

The same behaviour is also observed in the [hello instant app sample.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/hello)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base feature module needs to have an `application` reference to the application module in its dependencies. This allows the base feature to pull in the `applicationId` from the app module instead of using the one defined in its `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For example your base feature's `build.gradle` would look like:

```
dependencies {
   feature project(':feature1')
   feature project(':feature2')
   application project(':app')
   ...
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html#structure_of_an_instant_app_with_multiple_features) this will build all the flavours (paid & free) and pull in the `applicationId` for each one.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed it. But I did try that as a hunch. This answers my original question. But after installing the installed app over the instant app from android studio, my device launches the installed app and on pressing a button on the home screen (not part of instant app, just installed app), the instant app launches (camera) instead of opening CameraActivity as part of the installed app.